# How far could one tunnel towards the Earth's core?

Tags: earth, geophysics

Using current technology and virtually unlimited funds, how deep could we dig a shaft/tunnel with 1m bore (or larger), and what would be the limiting factor(s)?

If we push the envelope of current tech, how much further might we get with theoretically sound principles of increasing exoticness? At what point are you dealing with liquid rock rather than rock you can tunnel through and is that a final barrier?

Comment: You are asking a question about an enormous topic. As a flavour read [The deepest hole we have ever dug](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20190503-the-deepest-hole-we-have-ever-dug?referer=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F) and [Project Mohole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Mohole) and [Deep sea drilling project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Sea_Drilling_Project).

Comment: I could remove the expansion "if we push the envelope..." to limit scope? Or perhaps reword as "what obstacles must we overcome as we tunnel to greater and greater depths" - I'm coming at this as more a thought experiment

Comment: So read the reference that I have given you.

Comment: Unless you count hydrocarbons, you won't reach "liquid rock". Um ... unless you deliberately aim your borehole at a magma chamber. What could possibly go wrong ?

Comment: The biggest limiting factors are probably pressure and heat.

Comment: You mean an _open_ hole? as in, a hole filled with _air?_ I don't know, but all significantly deep holes are filled with _[drilling mud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drilling_fluid)_. The mud serves several purposes, one of which is to keep the hole open--its sheer weight [counterbalances the enormous pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drilling_fluid#Maintain_wellbore_stability) that otherwise would collapse the hole.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes a _tunnel_. I specified 1m diameter deliberately to distinguish from "how far can we drill" ;)